# How can I check for more than one constraint violation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, junit5, hamcrest

I have created a validator to validate the annotations I have defined in my model class ie `@NotNull`, `@Pattern` etc. Whilst writing my test cases, I created the below assertion which looks for one violation. However in some cases there is more than 1 violation. How do I amend the below to check for more than one violation? I essentially want to have an assertion like

`result.getViolations().size(), is(1 or more)`

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

    Set<ConstraintViolation<CreateRequest>> violations = validator.validate(createRequest);

    if (violations.isEmpty()) {
        CreateResponse createResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(clientProperties.getCreateUrl(), createRequest, CreateResponse.class);
        return new ClientResult<>(createResponse);
    } else {
        return new ClientResult<>(violations);
    }

        assertThat("Number of violations", result.getViolations().size(), is(1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the last line to:

```
assertThat("Number of violations", result.getViolations().size(), is(oneOf(1, 2)));
```

See [docs](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/) for `oneOf` method.

Tested with Hamcrest 2.2

Comment: Very true, but I'm looking to identify the number of violations ie 2 or 3.

Comment: Didn't understand your question properly. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, need to look at all the options Hamcrest provides.